# Why is my cat losing hair in small patches on her head?

Tags: cats, health, skin-condition, hairloss

I have noticed about two weeks ago that when my cat came back inside she was losing hair on the top of her head. There is a bit of dandruff, but the hair is slowly growing back. She is also showing signs of pregnancy, so if this is something to do with that, I have no clue.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! There could be some more causes which result in bald spots. From malenutrition (maybe caused by more needs while pregnant) over allergy to little animals like bugs or scabies. If the cat scratches the spots you should visit a vet in very near future. In general you should prefer the meaning of a vet more than the guesses of strangers in the internet ;) especially if you in worry about the health of your pet!

Answer (score 4):

> An unhealthy diet, poor health or an undetected disease can all be causes for your cat to lose their hair. As these are all quite broad reasons, it's important to visit your vet to identify the underlying cause. Some causes for hair loss in cats can also affect humans, and are contagious.

According to [this article at purina.co.uk](https://www.purina.co.uk/articles/cats/health/skin-fur-ears/hair-loss-in-cats#:%7E:text=An%20unhealthy%20diet%2C%20poor%20health,affect%20humans%2C%20and%20are%20contagious).

> Anxiety medications, synthetic feline facial pheromone spray, or other calming aids could prove helpful as well. Regular tick and flea control medication is also essential to keep the cat healthy and rule those pests out as a possible reason for hair loss.

According to [this article at thesprucepets.com](https://www.thesprucepets.com/hair-loss-in-cats-554758).

Answer (score 0):

one likely possiblity is ringworm fungal infection (the same organism that is responsible for ringworm in public showers). cats can easily contract it from other animals and dirt and is considered highly contageous. for this reason i must agree with the first response to not attempt to diognose or treat this condition without a proper visit to your veterinarian. ESPECIALLY if she is pregnant as it could spread to the infants who are especially high risk for contracting it.